# Ab Initio read multi files component runtime behavior

Tags: ab-initio

Does the Ab Initio read multifiles component close files when reading of the file is complete or when reading of all files in the stream is complete?

I'm reading in several thousand files and if the RMF component leaves the files open until the stream is complete I'll be hitting the ulimit for open file descriptors.

Thanks!
Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear to.  Hooray!  Closing this.